# Number theory research topics

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have to do a project for my number theory class (Undergraduate). The professor asked us to explore a topic from number theory and write about 5 to 10 pages on it.

I am a computer science major, so I really want a topic that relates to computing too.

I am personally interested in the twin prime conjecture and prime divisibility tests and algorithms

The prof said that the ABC conjecture is also a good one.

Can any body suggest other good topics ?

And your opinions whether it is good or not to make a project on the twin prime conjecture or prime divisibility

Comment: A good topic combining number theory and computing is [Pollard's rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm).

Comment: [$3n+1$ conjecture (aka Collatz conjecture)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). With relation to CS, you may give an overview of certain computational techniques and algorithms used in order to analyze this conjecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider [Collatz conjecture (aka the $3n+1$ conjecture)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

In conjunction with Computer Science, you may give an overview of certain computational techniques and algorithms that have been used in order to analyze this conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

Something like [elliptic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve), which are smooth projective cubic curves. Roughly speaking you can put a [group law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) on points of the curve, by a simple geometric method, and this group structure is also used in cryptography : as well as you can use $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$'s groups, you could used other groups, as those of elliptic curves.